# solr search for all possible combinations of a text

Tags: apache, solr

Hi I have a solr text field with input "Stack Exchange". How to search all the possible combinations of my input like "Exchange Stack" and "Stack Exchange" through solr filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use normal query `q=Stack Exchange` without quotes. it matches both "Exchange stack" and "Stack Exchange"

By default solr uses OR operator.

if you use quotes around querystring `"Stack Exchange"` its a Phrase Query it gives you results of documents which has exactly "Stack Exchange"

Comment: but when im giving without quotes im getting following error."error": {
    "msg": "undefined field text",
    "code": 400
  }

Comment: your schema.xml file should have field definition for field name text. check your schema file. which solr version you are using .?

Comment: I dont have ant field with text, but mu config file has  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>

Comment: ok. enter new copy field in schema file `<copyField source="fieldname" dest="text"/>`  change the fieldname to name of field in your document which has stack exchange value. and restart solr. it works

Answer (score 2):

it's easy , you need only set solr  q.op = AND

Comment: Thaks for your reply, but where to add q.op in solr admin

Comment: Find Raw Query Parameters item , then put  q.op=AND in input text 。

Comment: doing above getting "msg": "undefined field text" error